# as3 Making a scrolling Movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I was wondering if its possible to create a scrolling MC after children have been added inside of it thats extends the parents boundaries.  For instance I have a grade book UI mc, and inside of that I have a movie clip called student names.  Inside student names I have code to add another movie clip that will dynamically show a students name from a db.  The for loop repeats and another mc will be added below it.  However, after they are all added, the children still show outside of the parent mc (student names).  is it possible to make sure all the children inside student names stay inside the parent, and I can scroll down to see the rest of the children. (pretty much like a data grid)  The children being added are light and dark shaded boxes containing the student names to be easily read.

```
function addStudentList():void
{
    for (var i:int = 0; i < currentArr.length; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 != 0)
        {
            var darkShade:mc_darkShade = new mc_darkShade;
            darkShade.name = "darkShade";
            darkShade.x = xCoordinate;
            darkShade.y = yCoordinate;
            darkShade.studentName.text = currentArr[i].lastname + ", " + currentArr[i].firstname;
            studentArr.push(darkShade);
            addChild(darkShade);
            yCoordinate += 33.10;
        }else
        {
            var lightShade:mc_lightShade = new mc_lightShade;
            lightShade.name = "lightShade";
            lightShade.x = xCoordinate;
            lightShade.y = yCoordinate;
            lightShade.studentName.text = currentArr[i].lastname + ", " + currentArr[i].firstname;
            studentArr.push(lightShade);
            addChild(lightShade);
            yCoordinate += 33.10;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!
Josh

Answer (score 0):

I found a reusable, touch scrollable list of items suitable for AIR apps targeted at iOS devices. You can download the source code and also one example [here](http://www.infin8iphone.co.uk/downloads/iPadScroller/scrollListImages.zip), if you want to see one example, before you download, check it [here](http://www.infin8iphone.co.uk/downloads/IPhoneTester.html)

The files use [Greensocks](http://www.greensock.com) ThrowProps so you will need to download as well.